# Problems with MySQL OR clause

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with `AND` and `OR` clause in SQL. Here is my query:

```
SELECT  
    `act1`.`name`,
    `act1`.`surname`,
    `act2`.`name`,
    `act2`.`surname`,
    `act3`.`name`,
    `act3`.`surname`
FROM 
    `videos`,
    `actors` AS act1,
    `actors` AS act2,
    `actors` AS act3
WHERE 
    `videos`.`ident` = 'something' 
  AND 
    (
        `act1`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor1`
      OR 
        `act2`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor2`
      OR
        `act3`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor3`
    )
```

It returns me all variations of `{name, surname}`, but I want the name and surname of first exactly, second and third, if they exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need [`LEFT JOINS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join).

```
SELECT  
`act1`.`name`,
`act1`.`surname`,
`act2`.`name`,
`act2`.`surname`,
`act3`.`name`,
`act3`.`surname`
FROM  `videos`
LEFT JOIN `actors` AS act1 ON ( `act1`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor1` )
LEFT JOIN `actors` AS act2 ON ( `act2`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor2` )
LEFT JOIN `actors` AS act3 ON ( `act3`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor3` )
WHERE `videos`.`ident` = 'somethink'
```

The syntax you use is deprecated anyway, use `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` instead of listing table names in the `FROM` clause.

---

Your question sounds as if you could improve your model though. What happens when a video has more than three actors?

Using an intersection table `video_actors`

- video_id
- actor_id

would allow to do that.

Comment: +1 : Faster than me, and good point about normalizing the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use joins:

```
SELECT  
    `act1`.`name`,
    `act1`.`surname`,
    `act2`.`name`,
    `act2`.`surname`,
    `act3`.`name`,
    `act3`.`surname`
FROM `videos`
JOIN `actors` AS act1 ON `act1`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor1`
LEFT JOIN `actors` AS act2 ON `act2`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor2`
LEFT JOIN `actors` AS act3 ON `act3`.`id` = `videos`.`id_actor3`
WHERE `videos`.`ident` = 'somethink'
```

Comment: +1 for your answer too. I decided to use `LEFT JOINS` for all actors, but description sounds as if `INNER JOIN` is sufficient for `actor1` (as you have it).

Answer (score 0):

Because afaik MySQL does [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) when evaluating the where clause and thus creating the Cartesian product, in your case between the other actor tables. As others already mentioned, `LEFT JOIN` is much more applicable.

Comment: This would only work if all three actors are actually set. Also, implicit join notation should not be used any more.

Comment: @Peter Lang: As I said, `LEFT JOIN` is better. But there is no need repeat what you already said. I wanted more or less to point out how the boolean expression is evaluated. But if you say my code isn't working anyway, I believe you ;)